# Change format of "0 Comments and 0 Reactions" in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, disqus

Hello is it possible to change "0 Comments and 0 Reactions" into "0 Comments" or just "0".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case anyone is trying to do this on a system other than WordPress, you can set these in the Disqus admin panel under Settings -> Customise -> Appearance.

I changed "0 Comments" to "0" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

go to your theme folder and find the comments.php file

in this file you should be able to find were it prints the info to the page..

```
<?php comments_number(_r('No Comments'), _r('1 Comment'), _r('% Comments'));?>
```

Something along those lines,,,